# Check line for unprintable characters while reading text file

Tags: java, file, file-io

My program must read text files - line by line.
Files in UTF-8.
I am not sure that files are correct - can contain unprintable characters.
Is possible check for it without going to byte level?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to check a single line, or the whole file?

Comment: Is it guaranteed, that the line feeds are correct?

Comment: check single line. Yes, line feeds are correct.

Comment: Do you mean character which cannot be printed in a specific font? There are characters which are undefined in any font. This might be the same thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to check a string has unprintable characters you can use a regular expression

```
[^\p{Print}]
```

Comment: This, however, includes the whitespace and tab characters in your set of non-printing characters while they influence the place of the words in the page.

Answer (score 120):

Open the file with a [`FileInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html), then use an [`InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) with the UTF-8 [`Charset`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) to read characters from the stream, and use a [`BufferedReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) to read lines, e.g. via [`BufferedReader#readLine`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29), which will give you a string. Once you have the string, you can check for characters that aren't what you consider to be printable.

E.g. (without error checking), using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) (which is in vaguely modern Java version):

```
String line;
try (
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("the_file_name");
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
) {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // Deal with the line
    }
}
```

Comment: Or, for one less step, open the file with a FileReader and use a BufferedReader to read lines.

Comment: @stviper: And now it's 2015, I've updated it to use try-with-resources, much cleaner. :-)

Comment: @abhisheknaik96: Thank you for your edit, but only the `isr` bit was correct; the `()` are **supposed** to be `()`, not `{}`, and the last semicolon isn't required (but it's allowed, so I've left it -- more in keeping with the lines above it).

Answer (score 49):

While it's not hard to do this manually using `BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader`, I'd use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com):

```
List<String> lines = Files.readLines(file, Charsets.UTF_8);
```

You can then do whatever you like with those lines.

EDIT: Note that this will read the whole file into memory in one go. In most cases that's actually fine - and it's certainly *simpler* than reading it line by line, processing each line as you read it. If it's an enormous file, you may need to do it that way as per T.J. Crowder's answer.

Comment: Guava alse propose a method with callback
Files.readLines(File file, Charset charset, LineProcessor<T> callback)

Comment: If the purpose is to process line by line, using BufferedRead is as simple. It is also overkilling to add another library dependency just for line reading while the core Java library already supports that.

Comment: @user172818: No, it's not as simple... at least not if you're not using Java 7 with its try-with-resources statement. Additionally, I'd be *amazed* at any non-trivial Java program which couldn't benefit from Guava in *multiple* places. It's a great library, and I wouldn't be without it.

Answer (score 42):

Just found out that with the Java NIO (`java.nio.file.*`) you can easily write:

```
List<String> lines=Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/tmp/test.csv"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
for(String line:lines){
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

instead of dealing with `FileInputStream`s and  `BufferedReader`s...

Comment: Just want to add, java.nio.file.* is available since JDK 7

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the doc for [Files.readAllLines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) : _this method is intended for simple cases where it is convenient to read all lines in a single operation. It is not intended for reading in large files_

Comment: @fabian your're right, I'm using this all the time :)

Answer (score 11):

How about below:

```
 FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File("test.txt"));

 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

 String line = null;
 // if no more lines the readLine() returns null
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      // reading lines until the end of the file

 }
```

Source: http://devmain.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/java-quick-way-to-read-or-write-to-file.html

Comment: Nope - delete this - you are using default encoding - and entering a world of pain.

Answer (score 5):

I can find following ways to do.

```
private static final String fileName = "C:/Input.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName));
    lines.toArray(String[]::new);

    List<String> readAllLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName));
    readAllLines.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));

    File file = new File(fileName);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @T.J.Crowder is Java 6 - in java 7 the valid answer is the one by @McIntosh - though its use of Charset for name for UTF -8 is discouraged:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/tmp/test.csv"),
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
for(String line: lines){ /* DO */ }
```

Reminds a lot of the Guava way posted by Skeet above - and of course same caveats apply. That is, for big files (Java 7):

```
BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {}
```

Comment: An answer valid for Java 6 remains valid for Java 7.

Comment: @user207421 when there is a better way of doing it not really

Answer (score 0):

If every char in the file is properly encoded in UTF-8, you won't have any problem reading it using a reader with the UTF-8 encoding. Up to you to check every char of the file and see if you consider it printable or not.