# How do I get java to store a text file in a 2D array and locate a specific point in said array?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, file, text

I'm using Eclipse for this program and I'm trying to do is get the program to read the text file "ClimateDataA" and then find the date of the first time the temperature is under 80 degrees and I have to use for & while loops.

This is what the text file "ClimateDataA" contains:

> 14939  20140801    86
>
> 14939  20140802    90
>
> 14939  20140803    93
>
> 14939  20140804    87
>
> 14939  20140805    93
>
> 14939  20140806    83
>
> 14939  20140807    81
>
> 14939  20140808    83
>
> 14939  20140809    85
>
> 14939  20140810    85
>
> 14939  20140811    80
>
> 14939  20140812    81
>
> 14939  20140813    87
>
> 14939 20140814 89
>
> 14939  20140815    76
>
> 14939  20140816    87
>
> 14939  20140817    92
>
> 14939  20140818    91
>
> 14939  20140819    93
>
> 14939  20140820    96
>
> 14939  20140821    90
>
> 14939  20140822    93
>
> 14939  20140823    95
>
> 14939  20140824    91
>
> 14939  20140825    83
>
> 14939  20140826    81
>
> 14939  20140827    77
>
> 14939  20140828    82
>
> 14939  20140829    75
>
> 14939  20140830    87
>
> 14939  20140831    92

Column 1 is an ID number. Column 2 is the date. Column 3 is the temperature.

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class ClimateSummary
{   
    public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

    Scanner userInfo = new Scanner (new File("MyInfo.txt"));
    Scanner weatherData = new Scanner (new File("ClimateDataA.txt"));

    String userName = userInfo.nextLine();
    String userBirthPlace = userInfo.nextLine();
    int userBirthDay = userInfo.nextInt();
    String userBirthMonth = userInfo.next();
    int userBirthYear = userInfo.nextInt();
    String dataLocation = userInfo.next();

    int [][] myArray = new int[31][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

    }


    System.out.println("Welcome " + userName + "! This is the Super Computing Weathernator 3000!");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Name: " + userName);
    System.out.println("Date of birth: " + userBirthDay + " " + userBirthMonth + " " + userBirthYear );
    System.out.println("Place of birth: " + userBirthPlace);
    System.out.println("Data collected at: " + dataLocation);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The first day under 80 degrees is ");


    userInfo.close();

 }
}
```

Without these lines of code the program can run.

```
Scanner weatherData = new Scanner (new File("ClimateDataA.txt"));

 int [][] myArray = new int[31][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

}
```

This is the output I'm trying to get:

> Welcome Eric Hornberger! This is the Super Computing Weathernator 3000!
>
> Name: Eric Hornberger
>
> Date of birth: 18 February 1960
>
> Place of birth: Columbus, Nebraska
>
> Data collected at: Columbus
>
> The first day under 80 degrees is 15/08/2014

The first five lines are using data from the "MyInfo" text file.

I'm going to have to parse to get the date exactly like that in the output but I only need help with getting the data I'm looking for.

Can anyone help me do this properly? 
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Well, first of all, looking at the code you have, you have to populate your weatherArray with entries. Have you tried to call `weatherData.nextLine()` and see what it returns? (use `System.out.println()` for example)

Comment: what have you tried, what did you see and how did this differ from what you expect?

Comment: @Serhiy It gave me an error (I also changed the `weatherData.nextLine()` to `weatherData.nextInt()` because I declared the variable as an int) _Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: ClimateDataA.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at ClimateSummary.main(ClimateSummary.java:11)_

Comment: @Romski Beyond what I have in the code that you've seen I haven't tried much of anything else because I literally have no clue as to what I need to do. I'm pretty knew to coding.

Comment: @AirCode the exception is prettya explanatory, the problem is that your file is not present in the working directory, either create a file or copy it from other location to location where `MyInfo.txt` is located (should be in your workspace\projectName directory)

Comment: On tip: Look at the class java.text.SimpleDateFormat, that can help you formatting the dates as you want: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @aircode this site is for helping with specific problems, not for doing it for you. As Serhiy has said, your first problem is locating the input file.

Comment: @Serhiy @Romski I'm sorry if it seemed like I was asking for too much, locating the input `ClimatDataA.txt` isn't my problem here, I already know how that works which is why the `MyInfo.txt` parts worked. I'm asking how I go about setting up the 2D array properly if I haven't already and how I'm to call the specific piece of data (in this case located at [14][2] of the array).

Answer (score 0):

You should think of each line in your file as a separate string. Then you can split those strings into parts (id, date, temperature) and get the data from each column. Here is an older question about splitting up strings: 
[How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

And here is info on how to read the lines from your file: 
[Java read line from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413830/java-read-line-from-file)

So putting it together:

- Loop thorugh the lines in your file
- Treat each line as a String that you split (on blank space in your case) to get the data
- If the temperature value is lower than the previously found minimum, save the values in some variables

Hope that will at least help you get started!

Another thing also:
Since you are using Java, you might want to consider using an array of objects for you data instead of a 2D array, something along the line of:

```
public Class WeatherData {
   private int id;
   private Date date;
   private int temperature;

   /** Getters, setter, contructor etc */ 
}
```

That will make your program easier to read and modify when needed.

Comment: Thanks man I think this will help a bunch! I'll get started going about it using your advice