# check two different files in java and compare them

Tags: java, regex, substring

I have two file .First the property file and second the content file

**first file**

```
properties

{

"rowcount" : "3"

"delim" : "|"

}
```

**second file**

```
a|b|c

d|e|f

g|h|i
```

i want to  read both the file and check whether the second file follows the rule .(the structure of the first file will always be similar )

Comment: What you need to do is tell us what you've tried so far, and why it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all i think the first file should be a `properties.json` with this syntax:

```
{
    properties: {
        rowcount: "3",
        delim: "|" 
    }
}
```

With a [JSONParser](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/) you can read the JSON file and map it in a `Object`.

Then with a [FileReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413830/java-read-line-from-file) you can deal with the second file. For the validation part i think that a regular expression and a `rowcount` from the FileReader can easily solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, simply read in the `rowcount` number from the first file and compare to the [line count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453018/number-of-lines-in-a-file-in-java) from the second file.

For the second part, read in `delim` and then use a `Scanner` or similar to [read the second file using `delim` as your delimiter](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/SettingDelimitersforScanner.htm). If you only want a single character in between each delimiter, then test for this as you read the file, and throw an exception if you see more than a single character being read in.

From the example link:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    char[] chars = new char[100]; //If you know how many you want to read
    //(if not, use an ArrayList or similar)

    FileReader fin = new FileReader("Test.txt");
    Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);

    // Set delimiters to newline and pipe ("|")
    //Use newline character OR (bitwise OR is "|") pipe "|" character
    //since pipe is also OR (thus a meta character), you must escape it (double backslash)
    src.useDelimiter(src.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator")+"|\\|");
    // Read chars
    for(int i = 0; src.hasNext(); i++) {
        String temp = src.next();
        if(temp.length != 1)
            System.out.println("Error, non char"); //Deal with as you see fit
        chars[i] = temp.charAt(0); //Get first (and only) character of temp
    }
    fin.close();
    //At this point, chars should hold all your data
  }
}
```

Comment: **IlGala** @ actually the first file is created in mongodb and is converted as  a text file and is given to me .so basically i have two text file .like i have mentioned .

Comment: **River** @can you please provide a code snippet for the second part .

Comment: @avinash I have done so. Compiled and tested as well

Comment: @IIGala thanks .it is a  JSON file .so I could easily solve it