# Why isn't RandomAccessFile.seek(0); moving the pointer back to the start of the file?

Tags: java, android, randomaccessfile

I'm trying to use the RandomAccessFile class to read and write information from a `.json` file that I pulled from a `URL` to an internal file for an android app, but I'm having some trouble. I've made sure that I put `url.oponConnection();` in an `AsyncTask` so it doesn't have to run on the main activity, and I have verified that the information is being read from the `.json` file. (I have it output each line to my logcat).

Now my problem is that I can't read the file I created, because the pointer for the RandomAccessFile isn't being moved to the start of the file even after I've used `RandomAccessFile.seek(0)` I would like to make this file a `.txt` file if possible. I know this is a lot of code to read, but I have looked everywhere and I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

AsyncTask

```
public class AsyncTaskActivity extends Activity {

    public static class AsyncInfo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
    {
        protected void onPostExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Log.i("AsyncTask", "Loading...");
                // Make a URL to the web page
                URL url = new URL("http://api.wunderground.com/api/0c0fcc3bf62ab910/conditions/q/IN/Fort_Wayne.json");

                // Get the input stream through URL Connection
                URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = con.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                String line;

                // read each line and write to text file
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.i("AsyncTask", line);
                    TextEditor.file = new File(MainActivity.path, "siteInfo.txt");
                    TextEditor.writeString(line);
                }
                TextEditor.saveAndClose();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("AsyncTask", "DONE");
            return "Executed";
        }

    }
}
```

TestEditor class here is where I am trying to read and write the file

```
public class TextEditor {


    public static File file;
    private static RandomAccessFile in;
    private static RandomAccessFile out;
    private static String s;

    /**
     * Opens a file to be used for input (if not already open),
     * reads a line from the file, and returns the entire line of data.
     *
     * @return a line of text from the input file
     */
    public static String readString() {

        if (in == null) {
            try {
                in = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");//new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                in.seek(0);
                s = in.readLine();
                Log.e("readString", "STRING S: " + s + ".");
                return s;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Cannot open file for input!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return s;
    }
    /**
     * Opens a file to be used for output (if not already open),
     * writes a string to the file and wrties a newline.
     *
     * @param s The string text to be written. Follwing the string, a newline is added to the file.
     */

    public static void writeString(String s) {
        try {
            out = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
            out.seek(0);
            out.write(s.getBytes());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("writeString", "File Writer Failure");
        }
    }
    /**
     * Saves and closes the file (when opened for either input or output).
     * <p/>
     * Note: If the program terminates before the file is closed,
     * no data will be saved or written to the file.
     */
    public static void saveAndClose() {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
                in = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Cannot close input file!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
                out = null;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Cannot close output file!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the `.json` file

```
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "conditions": 1
  }
    }
  , "current_observation": {
        "image": {
        "url":"http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
        "title":"Weather Underground",
        "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
        },
        "display_location": {
        "full":"Fort Wayne, IN",
        "city":"Fort Wayne",
        "state":"IN",
        "state_name":"Indiana",
        "country":"US",
        "country_iso3166":"US",
        "zip":"46801",
        "magic":"1",
        "wmo":"99999",
        "latitude":"41.13000107",
        "longitude":"-85.12999725",
        "elevation":"242.9"
        },
        "observation_location": {
        "full":"Ludwig Park, Fort Wayne, Indiana",
        "city":"Ludwig Park, Fort Wayne",
        "state":"Indiana",
        "country":"US",
        "country_iso3166":"US",
        "latitude":"41.135193",
        "longitude":"-85.150581",
        "elevation":"774 ft"
        },
        "estimated": {
        },
        "station_id":"KINFORTW73",
        "observation_time":"Last Updated on December 14, 10:34 PM EST",
        "observation_time_rfc822":"Wed, 14 Dec 2016 22:34:42 -0500",
        "observation_epoch":"1481772882",
        "local_time_rfc822":"Wed, 14 Dec 2016 22:34:50 -0500",
        "local_epoch":"1481772890",
        "local_tz_short":"EST",
        "local_tz_long":"America/New_York",
        "local_tz_offset":"-0500",
        "weather":"Partly Cloudy",
        "temperature_string":"11.3 F (-11.5 C)",
        "temp_f":11.3,
        "temp_c":-11.5,
        "relative_humidity":"44%",
        "wind_string":"From the WSW at 4.9 MPH Gusting to 7.4 MPH",
        "wind_dir":"WSW",
        "wind_degrees":243,
        "wind_mph":4.9,
        "wind_gust_mph":"7.4",
        "wind_kph":7.9,
        "wind_gust_kph":"11.9",
        "pressure_mb":"1022",
        "pressure_in":"30.17",
        "pressure_trend":"+",
        "dewpoint_string":"-6 F (-21 C)",
        "dewpoint_f":-6,
        "dewpoint_c":-21,
        "heat_index_string":"NA",
        "heat_index_f":"NA",
        "heat_index_c":"NA",
        "windchill_string":"3 F (-16 C)",
        "windchill_f":"3",
        "windchill_c":"-16",
        "feelslike_string":"3 F (-16 C)",
        "feelslike_f":"3",
        "feelslike_c":"-16",
        "visibility_mi":"10.0",
        "visibility_km":"16.1",
        "solarradiation":"0",
        "UV":"0.0","precip_1hr_string":"0.00 in ( 0 mm)",
        "precip_1hr_in":"0.00",
        "precip_1hr_metric":" 0",
        "precip_today_string":"0.00 in (0 mm)",
        "precip_today_in":"0.00",
        "precip_today_metric":"0",
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_partlycloudy.gif",
        "forecast_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/US/IN/Fort_Wayne.html",
        "history_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=KINFORTW73",
        "ob_url":"http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=41.135193,-85.150581",
        "nowcast":""
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks over complicated. writeString is constructing a new RandomAccessFile() instance every time it's called. there should be no need to use a RandomAccessFile anyway. they are only needed when you are editing sections within a file. for text files like this you should be able to get away with using normal FileInputStreams and FileOutputStreams - and dont reopen them for each line

Comment: Thanks I will try to use those instead. I'm teaching myself how to do this and I have been so lost. I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: So I'm looking at the website below to learn how to use FileInputStreams and it says that it returns the bytes. Is there anyway that I can read the file and return the line as a string? https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html

Comment: you should really use a JSON library instead of rolling your own parse code, which will fail more often than you may think.  android has built-in JSON handling classes you can use, don't waste time parsing arbitrary object graphs yourself: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html.  also `RandomAccessFile` is not required for this, especially if downloading a stream via URL.  You will have to buffer everything first, because `JSONObject` wants a string as input.

Comment: @dusk wrap it with a InputStreamReader - this has a readLine method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413830/java-read-line-from-file

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to read/write the data as a string using a `Scanner` and a `BufferedWriter`. Here is the edited `TextEditor` class.

```
public class TextEditor {


    public static File file;
    private static Scanner in;
    private static BufferedWriter out;

    /**
     * Opens a file to be used for input (if not already open),
     * reads a line from the file, and returns the entire line of data.
     *
     * @return a line of text from the input file
     */
    public static String readString() {
        if (in == null) {
            try {
                in = new Scanner(file);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Cannot open file for input!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            if (in.hasNext()) {
                String s = in.nextLine();
                return s;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot read  file!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * Opens a file to be used for output (if not already open),
     * writes a string to the file and writes a newline.
     *
     * @param s The string text to be written. Following the string, a newline is added to the file.
     */

    public static void writeString(String s) {
        if (out == null) {
            try {
                out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Cannot create file for output!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            out.write(s);
            out.newLine();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot write file!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    /**
     * Saves and closes the file (when opened for either input or output).
     * <p/>
     * Note: If the program terminates before the file is closed,
     * no data will be saved or written to the file.
     */
    public static void saveAndClose() {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
                in = null;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Cannot close input file!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
                out = null;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Cannot close output file!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```